# Can I create an extension method for an existing method? And does it have to be a method?

Tags: scala

I would like to add a `charAt` method to `String` that takes a default value.

Can I even do that? How?

Also I love that trick where it looks like you're calling a method but you're really selecting an object. How does that work?

Answer (score 4):

Besides conversion to an expected type, the other two kinds of "implicit views" in Scala are when you select a member that doesn't exist and also when you apply a member that doesn't apply.

So for `x.f`, if `x` has no `f`, implicit search will look for a conversion that supply an `f`.

For `x.f(arg)`, if that doesn't type check, it will look for a conversion that supplies an `f` method that does type check.

```
➜  ~ scala -Yimports:java.lang,scala,scala.Predef,scala.util,scala.util.chaining,scala.util.control.Breaks
Welcome to Scala 2.13.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.3).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> implicit class R(val s: String) { def charAt(n: Int, c: Char): Char = Try(s.charAt(n)).getOrElse(c) }
defined class R

scala> "abc".charAt(3, 'z')
res0: Char = z
```

Because it only considers alternative methods in the case of a misapplication, it doesn't work to use an object of the same name, though using a different name works fine, because that is a selection like `x.f`:

```
scala> implicit class R(val s: String) { object charAt { def apply(n: Int, c: Char): Char = Try(s.charAt(n)).getOrElse(c) } }
defined class R

scala> "abc".charAt(3, 'z')
                       ^
       error: too many arguments (2) for method charAt: (x$1: Int)Char

scala> implicit class R(val s: String) { object charAt2 { def apply(n: Int, c: Char): Char = Try(s.charAt(n)).getOrElse(c) } }
defined class R

scala> "abc".charAt2(3, 'z')
res2: Char = z
```

Thanks to the original author asking about this; the question was too quickly downvoted as a duplicate, which it wasn't; it inspired a [bug report](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11866).